# Compare two variables from two breeds

Tags: netlogo

I still haven't learned how to compare two attributes from two different breeds.

In my example, I want to ask the breeds (healthy shops and unhealthy shops) to compare their revenues. The type of shop with the least revenues will close and the other type of shop will open in his place. The command to "compare-revenue" is the one that doesn't work. I know I shouldn't use breed, but I don't know how to formulate it differently without getting the "tick" error.

Thanks!

```
breed[healthy-shops healthy-shop]
breed[unhealthy-shops unhealthy-shop]

healthy-shops-own[
  total-earnings-h          
]

unhealthy-shops-own[
  total-earnings-nh 
]

to setup
create-healthy-shops 50
create-unhealthy-shops 50
ask healthy-shop [set total-earnings-n 2000 + random 2000]
ask unhealthy-shop [set total-earnings-nn 2000 + random 2000]
end

to go

compare-revenue
end

;;;;;;;;;

to compare-revenue

 let minhealth one-of healthy-shops with-min [total-earnings-h] 
 let minunhealth one-of unhealthy-shops with-min [total-earnings-nh]
    
  ask breed [ifelse (total-earnings-nh < total-earnings-h 
  [ask minunhealth [die hatch-healthy-shops 1]]
  [ask minhealth [die hatch-unhealthy-shops 1]]]
end
```

Another version using the let command (not sure if it is right)

```
to compare-revenue 

    let minhealth one-of healthy-shops with-min [total-earnings-h] 
    let minunhealth one-of unhealthy-shops with-min [total-earnings-nh]
    
  if minhealth > minunhealth [ask minunhealth [die hatch-healthy-shops 1]]
  if minhealth < minunhealth [ask minhealth [die hatch-unhealthy-shops 1]]

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you correct the typos: `ask healthy-shops [set total-earnings-h 2000 + random 2000]`  and `ask unhealthy-shops [set total-earnings-nh 2000 + random 2000]` I get an error "You can't use go in an observer context, because go is turtle/link-only".
That is because of the usage of `minhealth`/`minunhealth` without giving the respective shop. You can correct that by writing:

```
([total-earnings-nh] of minunhealth < [total-earnings-h] of minhealth)
```

This will make the code run until there are no healty or unhealty shops left and then crash.

You can change that by using

```
if any? unhealthy-shops and any? healthy-shops
  [compare-revenue]
```

Also, you have to change the order of `die` and `hatch`. Right now, no new shops are created, because the shop, it should hatch from is already deleted.

This would be the full code:

```
breed[healthy-shops healthy-shop]
breed[unhealthy-shops unhealthy-shop]

healthy-shops-own[
  total-earnings-h          
]

unhealthy-shops-own[
  total-earnings-nh 
]

to setup
  create-healthy-shops 50 
  [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set total-earnings-h 2000 + random 2000
  ]
  create-unhealthy-shops 50 
  [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set total-earnings-nh 2000 + random 2000
  ]
  
end

to go
if any? unhealthy-shops and any? healthy-shops
  [compare-revenue]
end

to compare-revenue

 let minhealth one-of healthy-shops with-min [total-earnings-h] 
 let minunhealth one-of unhealthy-shops with-min [total-earnings-nh]
    
  ifelse ([total-earnings-nh] of minunhealth < [total-earnings-h] of minhealth)
  [ask minunhealth [hatch-healthy-shops 1 die]]
  [ask minhealth [hatch-unhealthy-shops 1 die]]
end
```